# Parallel execution of randomforestSRC on macOS

Tags: r, parallel-processing, openmp, random-forest

I have a problem with parallel estimation of random survival forest from `randomForestSRC` package. I have followed the [this guide](https://www.r-bloggers.com/parallel-execution-of-randomforestsrc/) and tried installing it on Mac (Sierra). However, the `rfsrc()` function still runs on a single thread. Could you please advice what to do in order to achieve parallel execution, as the function takes ages to compute on a larger dataset. I have directly followed the steps described in the tutorial and no success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to set the number of clusters? `detectCores` will detect the number of your processor cores. Then `makeCluster()` to set the number of cores you want to use.

Comment: I tried the following setup before running the model: `registerDoParallel(detectCores() - 1 )  
options(rf.cores = detectCores() - 1, 
        mc.cores = detectCores() - 1)  
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide noted in your question is from 2013 and the process for successful OpenMP parallel execution has been significantly streamlined since then.  In fact, the binaries available on CRAN for the current build (2.5.1) should run in parallel on Sierra.  The source code includes a ready-made configure file that is the result of the autoconf command.  Thus, parallel execution is the default behaviour now.  If you haven't yet upgraded to the latest build, I would recommend doing so.  If the binary build provided by CRAN still does not switch on parallel execution, I would recommend upgrading your compiler to GCC using Homebrew or another package manager, and then appropriately create and massage a Makevars file as given in the instructions on our GitHub page so as to allow the CRAN package installation process to pick up the GCC compiler instead of the default Clang compiler:

https://kogalur.github.io/randomForestSRC/building.html